# How to build a Route53 route resource with cloudformation?

Tags: dns, amazon-route53

I'm building a Route53 route utilizing AWS::Route53::RecordSet resource within cloudformation template ( sample below).
I looked at some samples and quite didn't understand what the HostedZoneId and HostedZoneName parameter were, I should pass in the template below. Do i need to create some other resource before this. What do these parameter refer to - HostedZone Id and name?

```
 Record:
    Type: AWS::Route53::RecordSet
    Properties:
      HostedZoneName: !Ref 'HostedZoneName'
      HostedZoneId: !Ref 'HostedZoneId'
      Comment: DNS name for my instance.
      Name: !Join ['', [!Ref 'Subdomain', ., !Ref 'HostedZoneName']]
      Type: CNAME
      ....
```

Comment: Have you create a hostedzone? If so, it has id like ZXXXXXXXX and name, you can see on console. Use either of HostedZoneName or HostedZoneId.

Comment: @shimo - thanks. I have not . if you don't mind, what is a hostedzone?

Comment: A hosted zone is where you set records of DNS in AWS. https://docs.aws.amazon.com/Route53/latest/DeveloperGuide/hosted-zones-working-with.html